# Who led David to number Israel God or Satan?

Tags: 2-samuel, satan, 1-chronicles

In 2 Samuel 24:1 it says that the Lord God himself led or tempted David to number Israel but 1 Chronicles 21:1 says that the Devil himself did, is this a contradiction? and if no, then how could we as Christians possible answer and understand it?

> 2 Samuel 24:1: And again the anger of the ***Lord*** was kindled against Israel, and **he** moved David against them to say, Go, number Israel and Judah.

> 1 Chronicles 21:1: And **Satan** stood up against Israel, and provoked David to number Israel